# Drawing the bisector of an angle

Tags: tkz-euclide

[image]

(1). How to draw the bisector of the angle `CAB` so precisely? 
(2). How to introduce a point, say `P`, in the bisector?
Note that `CP` and `BP` must be perpendiculars.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \usepackage{color}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){M}
  \tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){A}
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
  \tkzDefPoint(12,0){N}
  \tkzDefPoint(10.5,0){B}
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
  \tkzDrawSegment(M,N)
  \tkzDefPoint(9.0,7){L}
  \tkzDefPoint(7,5.1){C}
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
  \tkzDrawSegment(A,L)
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a confusion where CP and BP should be perpendicular. So here is another variant.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \usepackage{color}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){M}
  \tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){A}
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
  \tkzDefPoint(12,0){N}
  \tkzDefPoint(10.5,0){B}
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
  \tkzDrawSegment(M,N)
  \tkzDefPoint(9.0,7){L}
  \tkzDefPoint(7,5.1){C}
  \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
  \tkzDrawSegment(A,L)
  \tkzDefLine[bisector](B,A,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
  \tkzDrawSegment(A,a)
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=0.6](A,a) \tkzGetPoint{D}
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--C](D)
  \tkzGetPoint{h}
  \tkzDrawSegment(D,h)
  \tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=lightgray](A,h,D)
  %
  \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--B](D)
  \tkzGetPoint{g}
  \tkzDrawSegment(D,g)
  \tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=lightgray](A,g,D)
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The main commands you are missing are `\tkzDefMidPoint` and `\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto...]`, which you can use as follows:

```
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{P}

\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--P](B)
\tkzGetPoint{R}
```

[image: Sample output]

Although the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) is in French, it includes many pictures, so it is often not so hard to find commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){M}

    \tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){A}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](A)

    \tkzDefPoint(12,0){N}

    \tkzDefPoint(10.5,0){B}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)

    \tkzDrawSegment(M,N)

    \tkzDefPoint(9.0,7){L}

    \tkzDefPoint(7,5.1){C}
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)

    \tkzDrawSegment(A,L)

    \tkzDefMidPoint(B,C)
    \tkzGetPoint{P}

    \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--P](B)
    \tkzGetPoint{R}

    \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--P](C)
    \tkzGetPoint{S}

    \tkzDrawSegment(B,R)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,R)
    \tkzDrawSegment(C,S)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,S)

    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,P)
    \tkzLabelPoints(P)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty try with MetaPost (inside a LuaLaTeX program), hoping it may interest some people here yet. I've done as if MetaPost couldn't compute the half of the given angle by itself, and constructed the bisector as going through the angle summit and the point P, which is computed as the intersection of the two perpenpicular lines. (Sorry for my approximative English.) The `whatever` variable comes in handy here.

The macro drawing the right-angle marks is not mine, I borrowed it from the [Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) by Hans Hagen.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef mark_right_angle (expr common, endofa, endofb, mark_size) =
 save tn ; tn := turningnumber(common -- endofa -- endofb -- cycle) ;
    ((1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1))
    zscaled (mark_size*unitvector((1+tn)*endofa + (1-tn)*endofb - 2*common))
    shifted common
enddef ;

beginfig(1);
  u := cm; pair B, C, P;
  C = 5u*unitvector (5, 6); B = 5u*unitvector (7, 0);
  draw  origin -- 1.25C; draw u*(-1, 0) -- 1.5B;
  P = whatever[C, C + C rotated -90] = whatever[B, B + B rotated 90];
  draw C -- P -- B; draw origin -- 1.3P;
  draw mark_right_angle(C, origin, P, 2mm); draw mark_right_angle(B, origin, P, 2mm); 
  label.bot("$A$", origin); label.bot("$B$", B); label.ulft("$C$", C); label.lrt("$P$", P);
  setbounds currentpicture to bbox currentpicture scaled 1.1;
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]