# Create angle bisectors in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

Suppose we have a triangle ABC of given coordinates. Let AD be its altitude. 
How can I draw the bisector of angle BCD? I'd like to avoid manual calculation of coordinates. I'd rather not use TKZ-Euclide due to its lack of English documentation.

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=below left:$C$](C) at (-2,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$A$](A) at (8,0);
\coordinate[label=above left:$B$] (B) at (0,7);
\coordinate[label=above right:$D$](D) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (C) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Closely related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227800/drawing-the-bisector-of-an-angle

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

\usetikzlibrary{through}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bissectrice}{%
    O{}     % drawing options
    mmm     % bissector of mmm
    m       % intersection point between base and bissector
    O{1}O{1}% extended drawing of the bissector
    }{%
    \path[name path=Bis#2#3#4] let
        \p1 = ($(#2) - (#3)$),
        \p2 = ($(#4) - (#3)$),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)} ,
        \n3 = {max(\n1,\n2)},
        \p1 = ($(#3)!\n3!(#2)$),
        \p2 = ($(#3)!\n3!(#4)$),
        \p3 = ($(\p1) + (\p2) - (#3)$)
    in
        (#3) -- (\p3) ;

    \path[name path = foo] (#2)--(#4) ;

    \path[name intersections={of=foo and Bis#2#3#4, by=#5}] ;

    \path[#1] ($(#3)!#6!(#5)$) -- ($(#5)!#7!(#3)$) ;
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=below left:$C$](C) at (-2,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$A$](A) at (8,0);
\coordinate[label=above left:$B$] (B) at (0,7);
\coordinate[label=above right:$D$](D) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (C) -- (D);

\bissectrice[draw,blue]  {B}{C}{D}{R}[1.1]
\bissectrice[draw,dashed]{D}{B}{C}{S}
\bissectrice[draw,dashed]{C}{D}{B}{T}

\path[name intersections={of=BisBCD and BisDBC, by=O}] ;

\node [draw=red] at (O) [circle through={($(C)!(O)!(B)$)}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Old version**

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

\newcommand{\bissectrice}[6][]{%
    \path[#1] let
        \p1 = ($(#3)!1cm!(#2)$),
        \p2 = ($(#3)!1cm!(#4)$),
        \p3 = ($(\p1) + (\p2) - (#3)$)
    in
        ($(#3)!#6!(\p3)$) -- ($(\p3)!#5!(#3)$) ;
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=below left:$C$](C) at (-2,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$A$](A) at (8,0);
\coordinate[label=above left:$B$] (B) at (0,7);
\coordinate[label=above right:$D$](D) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (C) -- (D);

\bissectrice[draw,red]{B}{C}{D}{1.5}{4}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is anything wrong with the old version?

Comment: Nothing, but the new one as more feature: calculation of the intersection point between the bissector and the opposite side , automatic name of the bissector.

Comment: @Tarass Why the following does not give me the angle bisector: `    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at ($(O)+(195:4)$);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(O)+(95:4)$);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(O)+(-5:4)$);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(O)+(-85:4)$);
    \bissectrice[draw]{A}{B}{C}{I}[2]` And I get *No shape named intersection-1 is known.*

Comment: In this really case, the there some bad rounding in calculations that prevent the intersection of the base and the bissector. I took off the /2 in the length calculation and in works fine. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 14):

Here's how you would do this with `tkz-euclide`: `\tkzDrawBisector(B,C,D)`

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-2,xmax=8,ymin=0,ymax=7]
\tkzClip[space=1]

\tkzDefPoint(8,0){A} 
\tkzDefPoint(0,7){B}
\tkzDefPoint(-2,0){C}

\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--B](C)
\tkzGetPoint{D}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,D)
\tkzDrawBisector(B,C,D)

\tkzLabelPoints(A)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](B,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

An inline `Asymptote` version:

[image]

```
% bisect.tex
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asy}
size(7cm);
pen linePen=deepblue+1.2bp, bisectPen=orange+0.8bp;
pair A,B,C,D,E; real CAB,ACD,BCD;
C=(-2,0); A=(8,0); B=(0,7);
CAB=degrees(C-A)-degrees(B-A);
ACD=90-CAB;
D=extension(A,B,C,rotate(ACD,C)*A);
BCD=degrees(B-C)-degrees(D-C);
E=extension(A,B,C,rotate(BCD/2,C)*D);
draw(C--A--B--C--D,linePen);
draw(C--E,bisectPen);
pair[] node={A,B,C,D,E}; string nodename="ABCDE";
pair[] nodepos={
  plain.E, plain.N, plain.W, plain.NE, plain.NE,
};
dot(node,UnFill);
for(int i=0;i<node.length;++i)label("$"+substr(nodename,i,1)+"$",node[i],nodepos[i]);
label("$CD\perp AB,\ \angle BCE=\angle ECD$",(A+C)/2,plain.S);
\end{asy}
\caption{Angle bisector with \texttt{Asymptote}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%
% To get bisect.pdf, process:
%
% pdflatex bisect.tex    
% asy bisect-*.asy    
% pdflatex bisect.tex
```

Comment: Following Thruston's comment on my own answer with MetaPost above, to find `D` and `E` I would suggest `D=extension(A, B, C, C+rotate(90)*(B-A));` and `E=extension(A, B, C, C+unit(B-C)+unit(D-C));`. The variables `CAB`, `ACD` and `BCD` become useless then.

Comment: @fpast: The reasons for the variables `CAB`, `ACD` and `BCD` are: 1) clarity; 2) one might like to know the values of the angles.

Comment: look at the above gkov's code, I see that the concept of `node` in TikZ is so handy and natural!

Answer (score 6):

One tikz solution

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=below left:$C$](C) at (-2,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$A$](A) at (8,0);
\coordinate[label=above left:$B$] (B) at (0,7);
\coordinate[label=above right:$D$](D) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);

%  first name the path
\draw[name path=t1] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[name path=CD] (C) -- (D);

% draw circle
\path[name path=c1] (B) circle (2);
% name intersection
\path [name intersections={of = c1 and t1, by={a,b}}];
% draw line beetwen intersections
\path (a)--(b);
% draw the bissector
\path[name path=bissec] (B) -- ($(a)!0.5!(b)$) coordinate[pos=3](ff) --(ff);
\path [name intersections={of = CD and bissec, by=c}];

\draw[thick,red] (B) --(c);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have drawn the bissector of CBD instead of BCD.

Answer (score 6):

With MetaPost, inside a LuaLaTeX program.

The `draw_mark`, `mark_angle` and `mark_right_angle` macros, which make the coding much longer than it could have been, are not mandatory at all to produce the figure, but I think that this bisector figure is made clearer by marking the angles accordingly. These macros come (slightly simplified) from André Heck's wonderful [tutorial in MetaPost](https://staff.science.uva.nl/a.j.p.heck/Courses/mptut.pdf). André Heck himself borrowed them from the [MetaPost manual](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf), and improved them at the same time.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=2bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef draw_mark(expr p, mark_size) =
    save t, dm;
    t = arctime .5arclength(p) of p;
    pair dm; dm = mark_size*unitvector(direction t of p rotated 90);
    draw (-.5dm -- .5dm) shifted (point t of p); 
enddef;

vardef mark_angle (expr endofa, common, endofb, mark_size) =
    save p, tn; tn := turningnumber(common -- endofa -- endofb -- cycle);
    path p; p = (unitvector(endofa-common){(endofa-common) rotated (tn*90)} 
      .. unitvector(endofb-common)) scaled mark_size shifted common;
    draw p; draw_mark(p, 5bp);
enddef ;

vardef mark_right_angle (expr endofa, common, endofb, mark_size) =
   save tn; tn := turningnumber(common -- endofa -- endofb -- cycle);
   ((1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1))
       zscaled (mark_size*unitvector((1+tn)*endofa + (1-tn)*endofb - 2*common))
       shifted common
enddef ;

beginfig(1);
  u := cm; pair A, B, C, D, E;
  A = (8u, 0); B = (0, 7u); C = (-2u, 0);
  D = whatever[A, B] = whatever[C, C + (B-A) rotated 90];
  draw A--B--C--cycle; draw C--D;
  draw mark_right_angle(C, D, B, 2mm);
  E = C + whatever*(unitvector(D-C)+unitvector(B-C)) = whatever[A,B];
  draw C--E withcolor red;
  mark_angle (D, C, E, 1.25cm); mark_angle (B, C, E, 1.25cm);
  label.bot("$A$", A); label.lft("$B$", B); label.bot("$C$", C); label.urt("$D$", D);
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `E = C + whatever*(unitvector(D-C)+unitvector(B-C)) = whatever[A,B];` is a little cleaner...

Comment: @Thruston Indeed. Adopted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @g.kov's answer

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
// Altitude and bisector with plain Asymptote 
// (without using the module `geometry`)
unitsize(1cm);
pair A=(4,0), B=(0,3.5), C=(-1,0);
pair Ct=reflect(A,B)*C;     // a point on the altitude
pair D=(C+Ct)/2;            // foot of the altitude
pair Et=C+dir(C--D,C--B);   // a point on the bisector
pair E=extension(A,B,C,Et); // foot of the bisector
draw(C--E,magenta);
draw(C--D,blue);
draw(A--B--C--cycle);

label("$A$",A,plain.E);
label("$B$",B,N);
label("$C$",C,W);
label("$D$",D,NE);
label("$E$",E,NE);

// with the module `geometry`, to mark angles
//import geometry;
//markrightangle(C,D,A);
//markangle(1,E,C,B); markangle(1.05cm,E,C,B);
//markangle(1.1cm,D,C,E); markangle(1.15cm,D,C,E);
////////////////////////////

label("$CD\perp AB$ \; and \; $\angle BCE=\angle ECD$",point(S),5S);
label("Altitude and bisector with plain Asymptote",point(N),5plain.N);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible,Fill(.5yellow+white)));
```

With the module `geometry` to mark angles

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a ruler-and-compass construction (although, of course, TikZ calculates coordinates).

The [`through` library](https://tikz.dev/library-through) is used to draw circles at a point through a point.
The `calc` library is used to find intersections of two circles via the `intersection cs`. Unfortunately, this is functionality is not documented in the manual.

You can use it either implicitly:

```
intersection <sol> of <first line/node> and <second line/node>
```

where (the optional) `<sol>` is either 1 or 2, i.e. the first or the second solution shall be returned and where `<first line/node>` is either the name of a node (of shape `circle`) or a line specification in the form of `<c1>--<c2>`. The same is true for `<second line/node>`.

The explicit specification is

```
intersection cs: first line/node=<first line/node>,
                 second line/node=<second line/node>,
                 solution=<1 or 2>
```

with the same parameters as above, however the lines need to be in the form of `(<c1>)--(<c2>)`.

I've used both versions in the code below.

---

With a style like

```
\tikzset{
  perpendic between/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    overlay,
    insert path={
      coordinate (middle of #1 and #2) at ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$)
      coordinate (perp-#1-#2) at ($(middle of #1 and #2)!1cm!90:(#1)$)}}}
```

We can do

```
% perpendics to ABC
\path [perpendic between/.list={B and C, C and A, A and B}]
     % find intersection of two perpendics: center of circumcircle of ABC
     coordinate (circ-BCA) at (intersection cs: first line={(middle of B and C)--(perp-B-C)},
                                               second line={(middle of C and A)--(perp-C-A)});
% draw perpendics
\path[thin,blue!50] (circ-BCA) edge (middle of B and C)
                               edge (middle of C and A)
                               edge (middle of A and B);
% draw circumcircle of ABC
\node[overlay,draw=blue, at=(circ-BCA), circle through=(A)] {};
```

and get the [circumcircle of ABC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB0ec.png).

---

Obviously, we could package this in another style like `incircle of=B-C-D` or `circumcircle of=A-B-C`. That's just more `insert path`s.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}
\tikzset{
  bisec from/.style args={#1 onto #2--#3}{
    overlay,
    insert path={
      node[at=(#1),  circle through=(#2)] (@#1-through-#2) {}
      coordinate (@#1-through-#2-to-#3) at (intersection of @#1-through-#2 and #1--#3)
      node[at=(#2), circle through=(@#1-through-#2-to-#3)] (@#2-circle)  {}
      node[at=(@#1-through-#2-to-#3), circle through=(#2)] (@#3-circle) {}
      coordinate (#1 onto #2-#3) at (intersection of @#2-circle and @#3-circle)
      coordinate (bisec-#1) at (intersection of #1--#1 onto #2-#3 and #3--#2)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\coordinate[label=below left:$C$] (C) at (-2,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$A$](A) at (8,0);
\coordinate[label=above left:$B$] (B) at (0,7);
\coordinate[label=above right:$D$](D) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (C) -- (D);
% find point on opposite side where bisec meets
\path [bisec from/.list={C onto D--B, D onto B--C, B onto C--D}]
      % find intersection of two bisecs: center of incircle
      coordinate (incircle-BCD) at (intersection cs: first line={(B)--(bisec-B)},
                                                     second line={(C)--(bisec-C)})
      % center of incircle projected on one side
      coordinate (incircle-BCD-point) at ($(B)!(incircle-BCD)!(D)$);
% draw bisecs
\draw[thin,red!50] (C) -- (bisec-C) (D) -- (bisec-D) (B) -- (bisec-B);
% incircle
\node[draw=red, at=(incircle-BCD), circle through=(incircle-BCD-point)]{};
% circumcircle of BCD
\node[overlay,draw=red!50!black, at=($(B)!.5!(C)$), circle through=(D)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The center of the circumference can also be determined via the `barycentric cs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PGF's own calculation with a custom coordinate system `angle bisect` that uses two keys `from` and `onto`. In your case

```
(angle bisect cs: from = C, onto = B--D)
```

specifies the coordinate on the line from `B` to `D` that intersects with the angle bisector. You can then draw the line

```
\draw (C) -- (angle bisect cs: from = C, onto = B--D);
```

The order is important and `onto` must be given:

```
(angle bisect cs: onto)
```

defaults to

```
(angle bisect cs: from = B, onto = A--C)
```

(similar how the `angle` pic default to `angle=A--B--C`).

As with the `angle` pic, only the names of coordinates (or nodes) are allowed.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfqkeys{/tikz/cs/angle bisect}{
  from/.initial=B, onto/.default=A--C,
  onto/.code args={#1--#2}{%
    \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
      {\pgfpointanchor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cs/angle bisect/from}}{center}}
      {\pgfpointlineattime{.5}{%
        \pgfpointlineatdistance{+1cm}
          {\pgfpointanchor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cs/angle bisect/from}}{center}}
          {\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}}{%
        \pgfpointlineatdistance{+1cm}
          {\pgfpointanchor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cs/angle bisect/from}}{center}}
              {\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}}}}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{angle bisect}{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/cs/angle bisect}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\coordinate[label=below left:$C$] (C) at (-2,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$A$](A) at (8,0);
\coordinate[label=above left:$B$] (B) at (0,7);
\coordinate[label=above right:$D$](D) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (C) -- (D);
\path coordinate (bisec-C) at (angle bisect cs: from=C, onto=B--D)
      coordinate (bisec-B) at (angle bisect cs: from=B, onto=C--D)
      coordinate (bisec-D) at (angle bisect cs: from=D, onto=B--C)
      coordinate (incircle-BCD) at (intersection of B--bisec-B and C--bisec-C);
% draw bisecs
\draw[thin,red!50] (C) -- (bisec-C) (D) -- (bisec-D) (B) -- (bisec-B);
\draw[thin, dashed] (B) -- (angle bisect cs: onto); % defaults to from = B, onto = A--C

% incircle center
\fill[red,draw=black] (incircle-BCD) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]